# display specific child div on mouse enter on php generated content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a code that displays event information from the database. the parent container's id is `show_id`. Inside `show_id` there is some hiden div `event_more_details`  with contents thats only supposed to show when i hover on the parent div which is `show_id` (in my case am using mouseenter function). Here is the code:

```
$('.show_event').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.event_more_details').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Problem is, if the php generates five events, when i hover on one event, the hidden div fades in all the other parent divs, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the jquery functions library i think i found an answer:

```
$('.show_event').hover(function () {$(this).find('.event_more_details').fadeIn(500);}, function () {$(this).find('.event_more_details').fadeOut(500);});
```

This works fine for me,by the way, @Ohad thanks alot 444 your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your HTML structure, you can use this:

```
$('.show_event').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.event_more_details').fadeIn(500);
});
```

`.siblings()` applies a selector to sibling elements. ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/))

Comment: I am trying out the siblings selector function but it isn't working.i'll look into it though, seems like the only way to go for now.but isnt there any other solution?